# Assets are not loaded in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using rails 5.1 and ruby 2.4. Assets are not loaded in production, but locally, assets are loaded, and the application is working fine.

Comment: Care to provide error you are getting to help you serve better.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

You need to precompile the assets for production:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bin/rails assets:precompile
```

You can find more on this [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#preprocessing)

Comment: I tried RAILS_ENV=production bin/rails assets:precompile but still its not working

Comment: What steps did you take to solve it? Did you run this command in the CLI on the server?

Comment: Yes i ran the same command, In production.rb file if I make config.assets.compile = true it works but this is not the correct way to do so, Im not getting correct sol to fix it.

Comment: Try running:   RAILS_ENV=production bin/rails assets:clobber before running the precompile

Comment: Tried running clobber and then ran precompile still not working.

Comment: check to see if any files are created in `public/assets`.